# How to edit .properties files with Spring Boot 2.5.2?

Tags: java, spring

I have 3 .sql files:

1. drop.sql (reset the DBMS every time I start the webapp)
2. schema.sql (contains the DBMS schema)
3. data.sql (contains the records of some users and some roles)

I also have 2 .properties files

1. application-sviluppo.properties (I use it on my PC)
2. application.properties (I will use it for the SERVER)

I wanted to update the pom.xml with **Spring Boot 2.5.2** but I can't figure out how I should change my files.

*File application-sviluppo.properties*

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.1.1.1:5432/test
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
# This code is deprecated but it works.
spring.datasource.schema = classpath:drop.sql, classpath:schema.sql
# This code is not deprecated, it is recommended but it does not work.
#spring.sql.init.schema-locations = classpath:drop.sql, classpath:schema.sql
logging.level.org.springframework=TRACE
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=false
```

*File application.properties*

```
spring.profiles.active=sviluppo
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=???
spring.datasource.username=???
spring.datasource.password=???
logging.level.org.springframework=TRACE
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=false
```

**I do not list the tests and attempts I have made because this page is not enough.**

I read here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.2/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties

**I show below a very simple and very short example that if you load it on your IntelliJ will clarify the problem.**

**Link to download the project:**

https://easyupload.io/yovn1a

**Problem:**

```
# This code is deprecated but it works.
spring.datasource.schema = classpath:drop.sql, classpath:schema.sql
# This code is not deprecated, it is recommended but it does not work.
#spring.sql.init.schema-locations = classpath:drop.sql, classpath:schema.sql
```

**DemoApplication.java**

```
package com.example.demo;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
@SpringBootApplication
@Profile("sviluppo")
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>gestioneutenti</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <packagingExcludes>
                            WEB-INF/classes/it/applicazionijava/gestioneutenti/CrittografarePassword.class,
                            WEB-INF/classes/application-sviluppo.properties,
                            WEB-INF/classes/templates/pagineapplicazione.html
                        </packagingExcludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

**schema.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS utenti (
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
    nome VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT utenti_pk PRIMARY KEY(id),
    CONSTRAINT utenti_uk UNIQUE (nome)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS persistent_logins (
    username VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    series VARCHAR(64) PRIMARY KEY,
    token VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    last_used TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

**data.sql**

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO utenti (nome, password)
VALUES ('kkkkkkk', 'kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk') ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
COMMIT;
```

**drop.sql**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS utenti CASCADE;
```

Comment: It's not clear to me from your question what change you're trying to make. If it's regarding the deprecated DataSource initialization properties, they have replacements in `spring.sql.init.*` as described [in the release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.5-Release-Notes#sql-script-datasource-initialization).

Comment: I did a lot of tests, I don't remember them all.
The only thing I can't fix is this line of code:
spring.datasource.schema = classpath: drop.sql, classpath: schema.sql
I cannot load drop.sql and schema.sql in development and only schema.sql in production (application.properties).
The deprecated solution works (at the moment I have left the deprecated version).

Comment: `spring.sql.init.schema-locations` is the replacement for `spring.datasource.schema`.

Comment: I think you are right but if I write "spring.sql.init.schema-locations = classpath: drop.sql, classpath: schema.sql" my webapp doesn't work. Spring Boot 2 has a bug. If I use the code you suggest the drop.sql file is not loaded. I opened this thread almost a month ago but haven't received a solution yet. It is a pity that Spring Boot does not have a dedicated forum and there is no email that I can use to report a bug.

Comment: Providing a [minimal, reproducible, example](/help/mcve) is a good way to make it easier for people to help you and to get an answer to your question more quickly.

Comment: There is no reproducible example for this question. I don't even know how to write this example. If you have any suggestions, I would be happy to open another discussion. My question is simply this: How can I split a database schema into two parts? On Spring Boot 2 (old versions) it was done like this:
spring.datasource.schema = classpath: drop.sql, classpath: schema.sql
On Spring Boot 2.5.2 how should I do it?
drop.sql is a file that deletes the database. It is used to start from a clean database every time I hit run from IntelliJ.

Comment: `spring.sql.init.schema-locations=classpath:drop.sql,classpath:schema.sql` should be all that's needed. I've just tested it with Spring Boot 2.5.2 and H2 and it worked as expected. If it doesn't work for you, create a minimal project (perhaps using https://start.spring.io) with that configuration that reproduces the problem and share it.

Comment: How can it work that between files it takes ";" and not ","?
Did you use "spring.sql.init.separator"? I use PostgreSQL.

Comment: spring.sql.init.schema-locations = classpath:drop.sql; classpath:schema.sql
Resolved classpath location [schema.sql] to resources [URL [...]]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%






spring.datasource.schema = classpath:drop.sql, classpath:schema.sql
Executing SQL script from class path resource [drop.sql]
Executing SQL script from class path resource [schema.sql]

Comment: `spring.sql.init.separator` is for the separator used to separate statements in the data and schema files. It defaults to `;` and I did not change it. Multiple values in  `data-locations` and `schema-locations` should be comma-separated. This separator cannot be configured.

Comment: https://easyupload.io/yovn1a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing deprecated `spring.datasource.*` properties that configure DataSource initialization and their new `spring.sql.init.*` replacements. For backwards compatibility, if you use any of the deprecated properties all of the new properties are ignored. To move to the new `spring.sql.init.*` properties you should update all of the deprecated `spring.datasource.*` properties to use their replacements.

Across your two properties files, you have configured the following deprecated properties:

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=false
spring.datasource.schema=classpath:drop.sql, classpath:schema.sql
```

In both files, these should be replaced with the following:

```
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.sql.init.continue-on-error=false
spring.sql.init.schema-locations=classpath:drop.sql, classpath:schema.sql
```

This leaves your two files looking like this:

###### application.properties

```
spring.profiles.active=sviluppo
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=???
spring.datasource.username=???
spring.datasource.password=???
logging.level.org.springframework=INFO
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.sql.init.continue-on-error=false
```

###### application-sviluppo.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.1.1.1:5432/test
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
logging.level.org.springframework=TRACE
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.sql.init.continue-on-error=false
```

Comment: I am amazed. Your solution is exactly the same as the one I tried initially. I had used ";" first and later also "," but I had not solved. I had done this test on another computer and with Spring Boot 2.5.1. I am speechless. I'll be going crazy, I'm baffled. Your solution works perfectly. I can't give myself an explanation of this. Thanks for your patience and I'm so sorry for all the time I made you lose. I am literally ashamed.